# SubSonic 3 SimpleRepository One-to-many

Tags: subsonic3, one-to-many

How do I handle relations in SubSonic 3 using `SimpleRepository`? E.g: Having Author and Book (see below) I want the assigned Author to be persisted when the Book is persisted.

```
[Serializable]
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114691/relationships-and-lazy-loading-in-subsonic-3-0).