# SubSonic 3: How do I link class/tables?

Tags: foreign-keys, subsonic3

While using SubSonic 3 I wrote the below. I thought I would get user_ref would be a column with name_list as its foreign key. My database ended up with just id and link with only the image_list table.

How can I have user_ref use name_list as its foreign key and have both tables in the database?

```
class image_list
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public name_list user_ref{ get; set; } 
    public string link{ get; set; } 
}
class name_list
{
    public long ID;
    public string username;
}


{
    var a = new image_list();
    a.link = "link";
    a.user_ref = new name_list();
    a.user_ref.username = "name";
    repo.Add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SimpleRepository [can't build foreign keys at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114691/relationships-and-lazy-loading-in-subsonic-3-0): it puts no logic in the DB, [just data](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Selecting_Templates).  If you want foreign keys, you need to build the db first, and use [ActiveRecord](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_ActiveRecord) or the [LINQ templates](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Using_AdvancedTemplates)...

Comment: So is there no way to build a database? I have to do it by hand or write my own sql code?